# Is there a way in selenium through which we can verify that the image displayed is correct and is not chaged with same file name

Tags: image-processing, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an application where I need to verify the cover Image of a book.
I encoutered a situation where the cover image changed and my script was not able to report this, since the the image source remained same.

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the hash of the targeted image doesn't change. Here is an example to compute the hash of an image with Selenium / Python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

JS_GET_IMAGE_HASH = """
    var hash = 0, ele = arguments[0], xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var src = ele.src || window.getComputedStyle(ele).backgroundImage;
    xhr.open('GET', src.match(/https?:[^\"')]+/)[0], false);
    xhr.send();
    for (var i = 0, buffer = xhr.response; i < buffer.length; i++)
      hash = (((hash << 5) - hash) + buffer.charCodeAt(i)) | 0;
    return hash.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    """

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")

# get the logo
ele_image = driver.find_element_by_id("hplogo")

# compute the hash of the logo
image_hash = driver.execute_script(JS_GET_IMAGE_HASH, ele_image)

# print the hash code
print image_hash
```

Or with Selenium / Java:

```java
final String JS_GET_IMAGE_HASH =
  "var hash = 0, ele = arguments[0], xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();      " +
  "var src = ele.src || window.getComputedStyle(ele).backgroundImage; " +
  "xhr.open('GET', src.match(/https?:[^\"')]+/)[0], false);           " +
  "xhr.send();                                                        " +
  "for (var i = 0, buffer = xhr.response; i < buffer.length; i++)     " +
  "  hash = (((hash << 5) - hash) + buffer.charCodeAt(i)) | 0;        " +
  "return hash.toString(16).toUpperCase();                            ";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");

// get the logo
WebElement ele_image = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));

// compute the hash of the logo
String image_hash = (String)js.executeScript(JS_GET_IMAGE_HASH, ele_image);

// print the hash code
System.out.println(image_hash);
```

Comment: Thanks, But can you help me with Selenium/java code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this without any image processing by calculating file checksums.